# Top Border pushes header down

Tags: css, html, border

For some reason, the following html works find without a top border.  But as soon as I add in a top border, the h1 is pushed down and there appears to be a blank line above it.

What's supposed to happen:

```
+---------------
| Title
+---------------
```

What happens with border-top-width:0px;

```
|
| Title
+---------------
```

What happens with border-top-width:1px;

```
+---------------
|
+-Title---------
```

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.css:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
    font-size:100%;
}

#title {
    font-size:87px;
    text-indent:5px;
}

#header {
    background-image:url('test.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:black;
    color:red;
    height:110px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-top-width:0px;
    border-right-width:0px;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-color:white;
}
```

test.png is a 110 pixel high PNG image.

Comment: I can't see the issue. Can you check my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/QJJ7m/

Comment: @roberkules You have *Normalized CSS* ticked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because by default (the default browser stylesheet) `h1` elements have a top and bottom `margin`.

When you add the `border-top: 1px`, the `margin` becomes the distance between the `h1` and `#header`, not `h1` and `body`.

A browser reset can fix this.

You will notice when ticking *Normalized CSS* in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3V9yf/), it works perfectly.

Comment: Indeed. For more information, the OP can do research on CSS "margin collapsing".

Comment: OK, I understand the margin collapsing.  However, why it works in jsFiddle, or on a "browser reset" (i just changed the margin, so I haven't tried the reset), is beyond me.

Comment: @Robert I think the browser reset zeroes the margin on `h1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#title {
    margin-top:0px;
    font-size:87px;
    text-indent:5px;
}
```